# how to get the previous line of a file after searching for one line?

Tags: unix

how to get the previous line of a file after searching for one line?
foe ex: there is a file called fore.dat containing:

```
:Server:APBS

        :Max Blocking queue:20

:Transport:000

        :Server:APBS

        :Max Transactions:10

        :MaxConnections:1

:Transport:001

        :Server:APBS

        :Max Transactions:10

        :MaxConnections:1

:Transport:005
        :Server:BIT

        :Max Transactions:10

        :Max Connections:1

:Transport:004

        :Server:APBS

        :Max Transactions:44440

        :Max Connections:1

:Transport:002

        :Server:BET

        :Max Transactions:10

        :Max Connections:1

:Transport:003

        :Server:APBS

        :Max Transactions:50

        :Max Connections:1
```

I want to print the Transport number containing server name as APBS.
i.e; the output as:

```
:Transport:000

:Transport:001

:Transport:004

:Transport:003
```

Comment: How are you searching? Are you inside an editor or using grep?

Answer (score 1):

With which command? `grep`?

```
grep -B 1 text file.txt
```

will give you the matching line and the line before.

Comment: any command. in grep -B is not valid.

Comment: @suvitha: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#benice

Comment: In Gnu `grep`, `-B` is valid: http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Context-Line-Control.html#Context-Line-Control

Answer (score 1):

As per [Eumiro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827797/how-to-get-the-previous-line-of-a-file-after-searching-for-one-line/4827811#4827811)'s response, `grep -B` will give you a number of lines before the match:

```
% grep -B1 '^duplicate$' /usr/share/dict/words 
duplicand
duplicate
```

If you want just this match, you could do the following:

```
% grep -B1 '^question$' /usr/share/dict/words | head -n1
questingly
```

Here's an alternative method, since you do not seem to have Gnu `grep` available on your AIX installation. This uses `sed` and `tail`.

```
% sed -n '1,/^another$/p' /usr/share/dict/words | tail -n2 | sed -n '1p' 
anoterite
```

Comment: but -B1 flag is not valid in kshell

Comment: @suvitha: This has nothing to do with your shell. Which flavour of Unix are you using? Solaris? If so, try `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep`

Comment: Then I suggest installing Gnu grep. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unix-fsoft.html (if it's not already installed) and putting that in your `${PATH}`.

Comment: is there any other way or command to do?

Comment: Probably loads. Here's one: `sed -n '1,/^another$/p' /usr/share/dict/words | tail -n2  | head -n1`

Comment: "print"? Printing was not mentioned in the question.

Comment: yup..i need to print the previous line of the search pattern.

Comment: Updating your question with the exact command you are using, expected output and actual output will enable me (or someone like me) to help you. Vague statements will not.

Comment: @suvitha: Updating your question may also help prevent people down-voting or voting to close.